# intrusive_ptr => _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, pointers

I use boost 'intrusive_ptr' in my code but when I delete some objects I got a crash !

In fact I use the same 'intrusive_ptr' into a class and return it, like this :

```
typedef intrusive_ptr<Node> ref;

class MyContainer
{
ref SmartPointer;
};

class Compiler
{
private:
ref MyNode;

public:
ref getMyNode() { return MyNode; }
    ref process() {MyNode.Reset(); ... return MyNode; }
};

MyContainer * c1 = new MyContainer();
c1->SmartPointer = compiler.process();

delete c1; <= CRASH
```

Comment: This depends on a lot of code, that is not shown here.

Comment: Are you sure that's the real code? You can't assign to `c1->MyNode` because `MyContainer` doesn't have a `MyNode` member. And `compiler` is undeclared. And there's no `process` function.

Comment: Sure, it is not the right code ! Because I have more than 200Kb of codes playing wiht this ! So, it is difficult to show where is the error in reality ! I just try to show what and where I think that the problem is ! Notices that I have update the example !

Comment: @user346113 Without proper compiling code, there is not much we can do.